# Discord.js Bot Error: 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning' When Announcing Role Assignments in Channel

Tags: javascript, event-handling, discord, discord.js, dom-events

I'm working on a Discord bot using discord.js. The bot's purpose is to send a congratulatory message in the #general channel whenever a member is assigned one of the specific roles ('alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta'). However, I'm encountering an error in my implementation.

**Current Behavior:**

- When a role is assigned, the bot should post a message in #general.
- I'm using the guildMemberUpdate event to detect role changes.

**Issue Encountered:**

- I receive an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error related to role comparison in my code.
- The error points to the line where I'm checking if a role was updated.

Code Snippet:

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!oldMember.roles.cache.equals(newMember.roles.cache)) {
        let newRole;
        newMember.roles.cache.forEach((role) => {
            if (oldMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) return;
            let roleNames = ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta"];
            if (roleNames.includes(role.name.toLowerCase())) {
                newRole = role;
            }
        });

        if(newRole) {
            const channel = oldMember.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "general");
            channel.send(`Congratulations on becoming part of the ${newRole.name} faction!`);
        }
    }
});
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- I tried using `if (!oldMember.roles.cache.equals(newMember.roles.cache))` instead of `if (oldMember.roles.cache !== newMember.roles.cache)`, as suggested in the comments.
- I replaced `.includes()` with `.has(role.id)` for correct role comparison.

Despite these changes, the error persists. I'm unsure how to proceed and resolve this issue.

**Questions:**

1. How can I correctly detect the addition of a new role to a member and announce it in a specific channel?
2. What is causing the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please add your current code, what you have tried, and what your problem is? Stackoverflow is not the place for you to ask people to do / make things for you. Please check out other answers, guides, docs, and try googling it first.

Comment: i have tried googling and everything, but there doesn't seem to be any mention of how to do this

Comment: Use `if (oldMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) return` instead. `.includes()` only works for `arrays`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`Client#guildMemberUpdate`](http://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) which gets emitted when something about a `member` property gets changed (i.e. a role is added). Try adding this code to your bot:

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // On `guildMemberUpdate`

  if (!oldMember.roles.cache.equals(newMember.roles.cache)) {
    // Check if a role was updated

    let newRole;
    newMember.roles.cache.forEach((role) => {
      if (oldMember.roles.cache.includes(role)) return;
      // Check for the new role that was added

      let roleNames = ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta"];
      if (roleNames.toLowerCase().includes(role.name.toLowerCase())) {
        // Check for only `['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta']`
        newRole = role;
      }
    });

    // Anything you want to run here with the `newRole` data.
    const channel = oldMember.guild.channels.cache.find(
      (channel) => channel.name === "general"
    );
    channel.send("Congratulations on becoming part of the faction!");
  }
});
```

Comment: `oldMember.roles.cache !== newMember.roles.cache` will always return true. Use [`Collection#equals`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=equals) instead.